# PHP while loop only displaying unique values

Tags: php, while-loop

I have an array with the following information in it:

```
Country          C_Count          C_Resp          Location          L_Count          L_resp

UK               100              10              London            20               5
UK               100              10              Manchester        80               5
France           20               3               Paris             10               1
France           20               3               Lyon              10               2
```

I am using a `WHILE` loop and want to loop through into a table that shows the Country, C_Count and C_Resp once and underneath the Location, L_Count and L_resp for each location.

At the moment, what is happening is that Country, C_Count and C_Resp is appearing as many times as there are locations.

The output would be something like this:

```
Country/ Location    Count     Resp
UK                   100       10
London               20        5
Manchester           80        5
France               20        3
Paris                10        1
Lyon                 10        2
```

Not sure this is possible within a `WHILE` loop - any ideas or suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: It's impossible to say what's wrong with your code since all we have to work on is an extremely vague description of the overall process. But this doesn't even look like a PHP question. Are you sure you aren't asking about SQL?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong about using a while loop. Without any specific code though, it's impossible to say what's going wrong.

Comment: You can't have two same key in array the last will overwrite the first

Comment: It's a PHP question as `DISTINCT` cannot be used in the MySQL query that brings back the information stored in the array.  Therefore, what I am trying to understand is if it is possible to loop through and only pull out the Country once regardless of how many times it appears and then the locations under the relevant Country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me try this:

get all available countries:

```
$countries = [];

function in_array_r($item , $array){
    return preg_match('/"'.$item.'"/i' , json_encode($array));
}

foreach($array as $a){
    if(!in_array_r($a['Country'], $countries)){
        $country['country'] = $a['Country'];
        $country['count'] = $a['C_Count'];
        $country['resp'] = $a['C_resp'];
        $countries[] = $country;
    }
}
```

Then echo country's related data:

```
echo "Country\Location\tCount\Resp";

foreach($countries as $c){
    $data = '';
    echo $c['country']."\t".$c['count']."\t".$c['resp']."\n";
    foreach($array as $a){
        if($a['Country']==$c['country']){
            $data .= $a['Location']."\t".$a['L_Count']."\t".$a['L_resp']."\n";
        }
    }
    echo $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
echo "<tr>";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT DISTINCT City_Operation FROM SA_State_City_operation");
while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option>".$user_data['City_Operation']."</option>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

See use of `DISTINCT` with mysql query.